# VSCode: Not enough space to split terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, there is a thing similar to command prompt in windows. It is called Terminal. In the past, I normally opened more than 3 tabs of this Terminal. However, in recent updates it displays this error when I try to open more than 3 tabs.

> Not enough space to split terminal.

Is there a solution or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

Menu: View -> Appearance -> Toggle Panel Position (it moves terminals to the bottom) or right-click the "TERMINAL" or other tab and select "Move Panel to Bottom".

You can now open an additional terminal (or more) and then use the same menu option to move them back to the right and it will keep the additional terminals open.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround - at least when You're using Ubuntu. You just have to unmaximize the window and resize it to make it bigger then Your screen size. Then You can split the terminal and can freely go back to initial window size.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, Windows won't allow You to have a window bigger that Your screen size. I don't know about Mac though.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I use Windows.